# Automapper not mapping nullable value correctly

Tags: automapper

Automapper is incorrectly mapping null value of nullable type to default value of not-nullable type

```
public class Product
{
   public Guid? ExternalId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductEntity
{
   public Guid? ExternalId { get; set; }
}
```

In case ProductEntity has null value for ExternalId, mapping to product results in Guid.Empty

Is this intended behaviour? We have no special mapping.

```
public class ProductProfile : Profile
{
   public ProductProfile()
   {
      CreateMap<ProductEntity, Product>();
      CreateMap<Product, ProductEntity>();
   }
}
```

We are using Automapper 7.0.1

Comment: Null should map to null. Only if the destination is not nullable you get the default. Upgrade.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu well, that is what I would expect, but I observe the behaviour as I described in the question

Comment: And I'm telling you what happens in the latest version.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu do you have any idea, what can I have wrongly set up?